# extending real solution to holomorphic function

Tags: complex-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Given a rational functions $f$ and $g$ defined on an interval $]0,a[$, $a>0$, a function $h$ satisfies in $]0,a[$ the linear differential equation: $$h^{\prime\prime}(t)+f(t)h^{\prime}(t)+g(t)h(t)=0$$ Can we assert that $h$ extends to a holomorphic function in the domain $D=\{z\in\mathbb{C}, 0<|z|<a\}$.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

No. For example we could have
$$ f(x) = 0 \qquad g(x)=\frac1{4x^2} \qquad h(x)=\sqrt x $$

Comment: Thank you Henning. If now we replace $]0,a[$ by  $]-a,a[-\{0\}$, does the assertion hold?

Comment: @mostafa: Then there'd be nothing at all to make sure the two pieces of $h$ would extend to a a single solution. Consider for example $f(x)=g(x)=0$ and $h(x)=|x|$.

Comment: My origin problem is in fact expressed in a system of differential linear equation as follows:
$$h_1^{\prime}=u(t)h_2(t); h_2^{\prime}=v(t)h_1(t)$$ where $u$ and $v$ are fractional functions holomorphic in the punctured disk $D^{*}(0,a)$ in $\mathbb{C}$. I am asking if the solutions are holomorphic in  $D^{*}(0,a)$ as well.